# How to append div with increment number based on button click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a button that users click if they want to add additional information. When the user clicks it will display a form. And if the user clicks the button add again. The form will be added again

What I'm trying to achieve is this

```
Name

if the user click add button again the form will be like this
Name (2)
Name (3)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".add_info").click(function() {

    let m = 1;
    $(".add_info").each(function() {
      $("#sibs").append(` 
                
                        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30 ">
                            <label><b>Name (${m+1})</b></label><br>
                            <input class="from-control" type="text" placeholder="insert name" id=""  >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30 ">
                            <label><b>Age</b></label><br>
                            <input class="from-control" type="text" placeholder="insert age" id=""  >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30 ">
                            <label><b>Email</b></label><br>
                            <input class="from-control" type="text" placeholder="insert email" id=""  >
                        </div>
                    
                        `);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sibs" style="border:2px solid #e0ebeb;border-radius: 5px;" class="row"></div>
<br><br><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-info ml-2 button-icon rounded-small add_info"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add </button>
```

And how do I fix the border to be like this

```
----------
|name(2) |
|age     |
|email   |
---------
----------
|name(3) |
|age     |
|email   |
---------
```

instead of like this ?

```
----------
|name(2) |
|age     |
|email   |
|name(3) | 
|age     |
|email   |
---------
```

Comment: Use [post increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment) instead of just reading the value, and initialize `m` in the outer scope.

Comment: The `m` variable needs to be declared outside of the click handler - otherwise you are resetting it to 1 each time. As for the border - well wrap the new elements you are adding into a container element with border then? Probably makes more sense to include the `.row` element in there, and append to a "plain" container element.

Comment: And using `$(".add_info").each()` there probably doesn't make the most sense either. Even if you had multiple such buttons - I doubt you want clicking _one_ button, to add these elements as many times as there are buttons in the whole document ...?

Comment: noted that i will fix this. tq for highlighting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remedy the problem with the number not updating: You're not changing the number, nor are you saving it between button-presses.

First, save (globally, e.g. in a global `var`) an `m=1`. Also switch from `m + 1` (which doesn't change the value) with e.g. `m++` which first returns the number, then increments it by `1`.

With regards to the border: Just pay attention to which element you're appending, and which element has a border! Append an element with a border, instead of appending into an element with a border.

```js
var m = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".add_info").click(function() {

    $("#sibs").append(` 
                      <div style="border:2px solid #e0ebeb;border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom: 8px;">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30 ">
                            <label><b>Name (${m++})</b></label><br>
                            <input class="from-control" type="text" placeholder="insert name" id=""  >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30 ">
                            <label><b>Age</b></label><br>
                            <input class="from-control" type="text" placeholder="insert age" id=""  >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30 ">
                            <label><b>Email</b></label><br>
                            <input class="from-control" type="text" placeholder="insert email" id=""  >
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      `);
   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sibs" class="row"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-info ml-2 button-icon rounded-small add_info"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid manually updating the counter if you wrap your "form" into a DIV and then count how many of those DIVs are already in the document:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#add-info').click(() => {
    // count how many info boxes are already in the page
    const count = $('#sibs > .info-box').length; 
    
    // create the info box adding IDs based on `count`
    const infoBox = `
      <div class="info-box">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30 ">
          <label><b>Name (${count + 1})</b></label><br>
          <input class="from-control" type="text" placeholder="insert name" id="name${count + 1}"  >
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30 ">
          <label><b>Age</b></label><br>
          <input class="from-control" type="text" placeholder="insert age" id="age${count + 1}"  >
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30 ">
          <label><b>Email</b></label><br>
          <input class="from-control" type="text" placeholder="insert email" id="email${count + 1}"  >
        </div>
      </div>
    `
    
    // append the new info box to the container
    $('#sibs').append(infoBox);
  });
});
```

```css
.info-box {
  border: 2px solid #e0ebeb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* styles below this line have been added just to make the sample look prettier */
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sibs" class="row"></div>

<button id="add-info" class="btn btn-md btn-info ml-2 button-icon rounded-small add_info">
  <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add
</button>
```